# Promises: How to pass data?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to understand how promises works. I see it's like a "chained callbacks"... more or less... but... it's possible to extract the values you get to a external value/array/object?

```
Promise1()
  .then(return x)
  .then()
  .then()
  .then(function(x){
    console.log(x);
  });
```

And how can I pass data from the first `.then()` to the fourth `.then()`?

Any effort to help me understand promises would be appreciated.

Comment: `(return x)` wrong - `.then` accepts only functions as arguments - non-functions are ignored, effectively passing the incoming resolved value to the next `.then` - the exact semantics of promise .then is described in detail [here](https://promisesaplus.com/)

Comment: The purpose of using `promise` functions is to gracefully handle asynchronous functions. Some examples of asynchronous functions are: `setTimeout`, ajax posts, writing to databases, etc. Your example doesn't require promises because it doesn't have asynchronous functions. Does this make sense?

Comment: Have you looked at the StackOverflow Documentation page on [Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201704061018404533805)?

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the example "promise" :P This is confusing for me :S Edit: I'll check the StackOverflow documentation

Answer (score 3):

You can do it but you need to pass the `x` value from one `then` to another:

```
Promise1()
    .then(function() {
        return x; // The "x" is wrapped in a resolved promise by "then method"
    })
    .then(function(x) { // The "then" pass to the fulfillment callback the value inside the promise taken in input, which is the "x" value
        return x; //Same as above, we return the "x" value to pass it to the next "then" function
    })
    .then(function(x) { // Same as above
        return x; // Same as above
    })
    .then(function (x) { 
        console.log(x); // Here you can access the "x" value and print it
    })
```

Comment: This make sens for me (rigth now I can't test it, but looks nice). Is the a possible way to pass/store data in a external variable?

Comment: You can do it but is not the correct practice, it can be very dangerous if the external variable is modified by side effects. You usually pass `x` from the first `then` to the second one and the latter takes `x`, use it to build `y` and returns it. Then the third `then` takes `y` and use it to construct `z` which is returned and so on...

Comment: Then, how can I return data from the last ".then()" to aonther funtion? This is confusing for me XD

Comment: The last `.then()` will return a promise. You can return this promise to another function which will can access the value inside this promise calling `.then()` on it.

Comment: So ".then()" returns a promise... whcich I need to resolve using other ".then()"?

Comment: Well, then return a promise which _can_ be resolved or rejected. To access the value of a resolved or rejected promise you should call `then` on it. ? Never forget that promises are used to access value of async operations, so you cannot simple read the value contained inside the promise as you would do in with a sync call.

Comment: Ohhh..... now I get it. Well... thenI think I should change my code.,.. or study another way to achieve my goal. Thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 3):

The [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

So, you can use many `then` as you need returning `x` and doing something with that returned `x`... and so on

Code example:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    Promise1 = x => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Your logic...
        setTimeout(() => 
          x <= 4 
            ? resolve('Success!') 
            : reject('Rejected!')
          , 600 * x);
      });
    },
    logMessage = (x, msg) => console.log(`For item ${x} result: ${msg}`);

array.forEach(x => Promise1(x)
  .then(x => x)
  .then(x => x)
  .then(x => x)
  .then(x => x)
  .then(message => logMessage(x, message))
  .catch(reason => logMessage(x, reason))
);
```

Notice that as the `then` and [Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods return promises, they can be chained — an operation called composition.

Answer (score -1):

## 1

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  return doSomethingElse();
}).then(finalHandler);

    doSomething
    |-----------------|
                      doSomethingElse(undefined)
                      |------------------|
                                         finalHandler(resultOfDoSomethingElse)
                                         |------------------|
```

## 2

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  doSomethingElse();
}).then(finalHandler);

doSomething
|-----------------|
                  doSomethingElse(undefined)
                  |------------------|
                  finalHandler(undefined)
                  |------------------|
```

3

```
doSomething().then(doSomethingElse())
  .then(finalHandler);

doSomething
|-----------------|
doSomethingElse(undefined)
|---------------------------------|
                  finalHandler(resultOfDoSomething)
                  |------------------|
```

4

```
doSomething().then(doSomethingElse)
  .then(finalHandler);

doSomething
|-----------------|
                  doSomethingElse(resultOfDoSomething)
                  |------------------|
                                     finalHandler(resultOfDoSomethingElse)
                                     |------------------|
```

https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html